Convert JSON to table when all JSON field keys are unknown/arbitrary/random
There is a table in Oracle that has huge number of rows with JSON objects which have unknown/arbitrary/random field keys!
Basically those JSON objects are industrial products specifications. There are over 20k categories and 2M products. The JSON looks like {"max. temp.": "40 F", "I.D.": "1/3 in", ...}
How to convert JSON like { "a": 8, "b":27 } to a table like:
key | val
--- | ---
a   | 8
b   | 27

in case when all JSON field keys are unknown/arbitrary/random?

To clarify, it sounds like you want one table per product/object, with the table having two columns (key, value) and as many rows as the corresponding product/object has properties. Is that correct?

If the above is correct, you are going to have an obscene amount of tables (2 million). I suspect a better approach would be to divide your 20k keys into super-categories, then have 1 table per super-category, with one column per key, and one row for each product that specifies one of the super-categories. Alternatively, you could take your 100 most common keys, have those be columns, and have an "other" column with stores the JSON for all of the other categories not included in your top 100.

@PatrickvD Yes, it's correct.
To be precise, I need not a table but a query that converts JSON to "tabular" representation.
If I would have a such great query then I could use it as a start point to process products specifications. I'm not going to create 2M tables.

You can do it in PL/SQL using the json_object_t type which has a get_keys function. It's also possible to use JSON_DATA_GUIDE but since the schema of each row is different you may not get the max benefit you could expect, even with search index on the JSON column. See AskTom site and the ref. links: https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/asktom.search?tag=obtain-all-json-keys-from-json-columns

Maybe consider a document based (i.e NoSQL database) or instead of PL/SQL a programming language which is more related to JSON, e.g. Node.js with node-oracledb. For example in MongoDB you can use $objectToArray or in Node.js it would be single line.

You can create the types and function:
CREATE TYPE key_value_pair IS OBJECT(
  key   VARCHAR2(4000),
  value VARCHAR2(4000)
);

CREATE TYPE key_value_list IS TABLE OF key_value_pair;

CREATE FUNCTION get_key_values(
  json IN CLOB
) RETURN key_value_list PIPELINED
IS
  doc_keys JSON_KEY_LIST;
  obj      JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE ( json );
BEGIN
  doc_keys := obj.GET_KEYS;
  FOR i IN 1 .. doc_keys.COUNT LOOP
    PIPE ROW ( key_value_pair( doc_keys(i), obj.get_string(doc_keys(i) ) ) );
  END LOOP;
END get_key_values;
/

Then, from Oracle 12, you can use the query:
SELECT t.id,
       kv.key,
       kv.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY get_key_values(t.json_value) kv;

Which outputs:



ID
KEY
VALUE




1
max. temp.
40 F


1
I.D.
1/3 in


2
a
8


2
b
27


3
"a": 8
2,3,4


3
a:b
a,b,c




Alternative solution
You can create the function:
CREATE FUNCTION get_key(
  pos  IN PLS_INTEGER,
  json IN CLOB
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
  doc_keys JSON_KEY_LIST;
BEGIN
  doc_keys := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE ( json ).GET_KEYS;
  RETURN doc_keys( pos );
END get_key;
/

Then, from Oracle 12, you can use the query:
SELECT t.id,
       get_key(j.idx, t.json_value) AS key,
       j.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.json_value,
         '$.*'
         COLUMNS (
           idx FOR ORDINALITY,
           value VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$'
         )
       ) j

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id NUMBER, json_value CLOB CHECK (json_value IS JSON));
INSERT INTO table_name (id, json_value) VALUES (1, '{"max. temp.": "40 F", "I.D.": "1/3 in"}');
INSERT INTO table_name (id, json_value) VALUES (2, '{ "a": 8, "b":27 }');
INSERT INTO table_name (id, json_value) VALUES (3, '{ "\"a\": 8": "2,3,4", "a:b":"a,b,c" }')

Also outputs:



ID
KEY
VALUE




1
max. temp.
40 F


1
I.D.
1/3 in


2
a
8


2
b
27


3
"a": 8
2,3,4


3
a:b
a,b,c




In later Oracle versions, you can declare the function as part of the query:
WITH FUNCTION get_key(
  pos  IN PLS_INTEGER,
  json IN CLOB
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS
  doc_keys JSON_KEY_LIST;
BEGIN
  doc_keys := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE ( json ).GET_KEYS;
  RETURN doc_keys( pos );
END get_key;
SELECT t.id,
       get_key(j.idx, t.json_value) AS key,
       j.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.json_value,
         '$.*'
         COLUMNS (
           idx FOR ORDINALITY,
           value VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '$'
         )
       ) j

Which outputs the same.
fiddle

This means a PARSE per key in the JSON of each row, with 20M rows, hope they don't have a mean of 40 keys per row... if the mean of keys per row is high better write a PIPELINED function doing the job with only 1 call to PARSE. Or if the goal is to insert into a table write a PROCEDURE doing the job.

@p3consulting Yes, updated to include a PIPELINED function.

If your json specifications are constructed as described in the question (a simple array of key:value paires) - there is an option to extract keys and values using recursive cte-s with good old character functions: Substr(), Instr(), Replace(), ... This will not work with complex json structures ...
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table specs ( product_id Number(6), spec VarChar2(4000) );
Insert Into specs
      Select 1, '{"max.temp.": "40 F", "I.D.": "1/3 in"}' From Dual Union All
      Select 2, '{"a": 8, "b":27 }' From Dual Union All
      Select 3, '{"energ.eff.class": "A++", "some other spec":"27", "status": "OK" }' From Dual

WITH      --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E s :
    keys ( pass, product_id, spec, keys, rest, total_spec) AS
      ( Select 1, product_id, spec, 
               Replace(Replace(SubStr(spec, 1, InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1)-2), '{ "', ''), '{"', '') as keys,
               SubStr(spec, Instr(spec, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               Length(spec) - Length(Replace(spec, ':', ''))  as total_spec
        From   specs
       UNION ALL 
        Select pass + 1, product_id, spec, 
               Replace(Replace(SubStr(rest, 1, InStr(rest, ':', 1, 1)-2), ' "', ''), '*') as keys, 
               SubStr(rest, Instr(rest, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               total_spec
        From   keys
        Where  pass < total_spec
      ), 
    vals ( pass, product_id, spec, vals, rest, total_spec) AS
      ( Select 1, product_id, spec, 
               Replace(LTRIM(SubStr(spec, InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1)+1, ( InStr(spec, ',', 1, 1) - InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1) ) - 1 )), '"', '')  as vals,
               SubStr(spec, Instr(spec, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               Length(spec) - Length(Replace(spec, ':', ''))  as total_spec
        From   specs  
       UNION ALL
        Select pass + 1, product_id, spec, 
               Replace(Replace(LTRIM(SubStr(rest, InStr(rest, ':', 1, 1)+1, ( InStr(spec, ',', 1, 1) - InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1) ) - 1) ), '"', ''), ',', '')  as vals,
               SubStr(rest, Instr(rest, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               total_spec
        From   vals
        Where  pass < total_spec
      )

--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select    s.product_id, k.keys as key, v.vals as val
From      specs s
Left Join keys k ON(k.product_id = s.product_id)
Left Join vals v ON(v.product_id = s.product_id And v.pass = k.pass)
Order By  s.product_id, k.pass

/*      R e s u l t : 
PRODUCT_ID  KEY               VAL
----------  ----------------  -------------
         1  max.temp.         40 F
         1  I.D.              1/3 i
         2  a                 8
         2  b                 27
         3  energ.eff.class   A++
         3  some other spec   27
         3  status            OK

See the fiddle here.
The above code has two recursive queries - one for keys and one for values. This could be done with one recursive query getting both keys and values in the same processing. The code is just a bit different and, with sample data used, the result is the same:
WITH    --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E :     (keys & vals)
    keys_vals ( pass, product_id, spec, keys, vals, rest, total_spec) AS
      ( Select 1, product_id, spec, 
               Replace(Replace(SubStr(spec, 1, InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1)-2), '{ "', ''), '{"', '') as keys,
               Replace(LTRIM(SubStr(spec, InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1)+1, ( InStr(spec, ',', 1, 1) - InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1) ) - 1 )), '"', '')  as vals,
               SubStr(spec, Instr(spec, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               Length(spec) - Length(Replace(spec, ':', ''))  as total_spec
        From   specs
       UNION ALL 
        Select pass + 1, product_id, spec, 
               Replace(Replace(SubStr(rest, 1, InStr(rest, ':', 1, 1)-2), ' "', ''), '*') as keys, 
               Replace(Replace(LTRIM(SubStr(rest, InStr(rest, ':', 1, 1)+1, ( InStr(spec, ',', 1, 1) - InStr(spec, ':', 1, 1) ) - 1) ), '"', ''), ',', '')  as vals,
               SubStr(rest, Instr(rest, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               total_spec
        From   keys_vals
        Where  pass < total_spec
      )

--    M a i n    S Q L : 
Select s.product_id, kv.keys as key, kv.vals as val
From   specs s
Left Join keys_vals kv ON(kv.product_id = s.product_id)
Order By  s.product_id, kv.pass

See the fiddle here.

If I would have a such great query then I could use it as a start point to process products specifications.

If you want to use it as a query that would process any json string data resulting with key and val columns:
--   With json_key_val_data = '{"energ.eff.class": "A++", "some other spec":"27", "status": "OK" }'
WITH
  json_data (json_key_val_data) as
      ( Select '{"energ.eff.class": "A++", "some other spec":"27", "status": "OK" }' 
        From    Dual),
  keys_vals ( pass, json_key_val_data, keys, vals, rest, total_json_key_val_data) AS
      ( Select 1, json_key_val_data, 
               Replace(Replace(SubStr(json_key_val_data, 1, InStr(json_key_val_data, ':', 1, 1)-2), '{ "', ''), '{"', '') as keys,
               Replace(LTRIM(SubStr(json_key_val_data, InStr(json_key_val_data, ':', 1, 1)+1, ( InStr(json_key_val_data, ',', 1, 1) - InStr(json_key_val_data, ':', 1, 1) ) - 1 )), '"', '')  as vals,
               SubStr(json_key_val_data, Instr(json_key_val_data, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               Length(json_key_val_data) - Length(Replace(json_key_val_data, ':', ''))  as total_json_key_val_data
        From   json_data
       UNION ALL 
        Select pass + 1, json_key_val_data, 
               Replace(Replace(SubStr(rest, 1, InStr(rest, ':', 1, 1)-2), ' "', ''), '*') as keys, 
               Replace(Replace(LTRIM(SubStr(rest, InStr(rest, ':', 1, 1)+1, ( InStr(json_key_val_data, ',', 1, 1) - InStr(json_key_val_data, ':', 1, 1) ) - 1) ), '"', ''), ',', '')  as vals,
               SubStr(rest, Instr(rest, ',', 1, 1)+1) as rest,
               total_json_key_val_data
        From   keys_vals
        Where  pass < total_json_key_val_data
      )
Select    pass as rn, keys as key, vals as val
From      keys_vals 
Order By  pass

/*      R e s u l t : 
        RN  KEY               VAL
----------  ----------------  -------------
         1  energ.eff.class   A++
         2  some other spec   27
         3  status            OK           */


as long as you don't have the separation characters (,:) in the keys or values...

@p3consulting That is true. It looks like it should work, though, with specific single category/parameter/property and it's value. But, yes, there could be some separation character within key/val that would couse bad result in those rows.

This fails in other ways as well. It won't get the correct key value if there are multiple spaces before the key or any spaces after the key and will not properly evaluate escaped characters in strings and will strip escaped quotes from strings. fiddle

@MT0 Yes, that is a fact, and a reason that the very, very first words of the answer are: "If your json specifications are constructed as described in the question....". On the other hand, if they have 2M of poorly structured (or unstructured) json strings then they have a bigger problem. If the data are like stated in the question - this will work except the separation chars as p3consulting already commented. The : probably could be handled in most cases but the comma - I'd say not.

They could all be handled with a regular expression that looks for valid JSON key-value pairs (assuming that there are no nested objects or arrays) - however, parsing JSON (or XML) should NOT be done using string functions, a proper parser should be used.

@MTO Which bring us to the start of this - poorly structured json strings would not work.

Don't use this, use a proper JSON parser.
As an academic exercise, you can parse simple JSON objects (without nested objects or arrays) using regular expressions in a recursive query:
WITH key_values (id, json_value, key, value) AS (
  SELECT id,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           json_value,
           '^\s*{\s*("([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*")\s*'
           || ':'
           || '\s*('
           || '"([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*"'
           || '|true|false|null'
           || '|-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE]-?\d+)?'
           || ')\s*((,.*)?})\s*$',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           8
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           json_value,
           '^\s*{\s*("([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*")\s*'
           || ':'
           || '\s*('
           || '"([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*"'
           || '|true|false|null'
           || '|-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE]-?\d+)?'
           || ')\s*((,.*)?})\s*$',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           json_value,
           '^\s*{\s*("([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*")\s*'
           || ':'
           || '\s*('
           || '"([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*"'
           || '|true|false|null'
           || '|-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE]-?\d+)?'
           || ')\s*((,.*)?})\s*$',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           3
         )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           json_value,
           '^,\s*("([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*")\s*'
           || ':'
           || '\s*('
           || '"([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*"'
           || '|true|false|null'
           || '|-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE]-?\d+)?'
           || ')\s*((,.*)?})\s*$',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           8
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           json_value,
           '^,\s*("([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*")\s*'
           || ':'
           || '\s*('
           || '"([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*"'
           || '|true|false|null'
           || '|-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE]-?\d+)?'
           || ')\s*((,.*)?})\s*$',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           1
         ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           json_value,
           ',\s*("([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*")\s*'
           || ':'
           || '\s*('
           || '"([^\"]|\\[\/bfrtn"]|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})*"'
           || '|true|false|null'
           || '|-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE]-?\d+)?'
           || ')\s*((,.*)?})\s*$',
           1,
           1,
           NULL,
           3
         )
  FROM   key_values
  WHERE  json_value != '}'
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT id,
       key,
       value
FROM   key_values

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id NUMBER, json_value VARCHAR2(4000) CHECK (json_value IS JSON));
INSERT INTO table_name (id, json_value) VALUES (1, '{"max. temp.": "40 F", "I.D.": "1/3 in"}');
INSERT INTO table_name (id, json_value) VALUES (2, '{ "a": 8, "b":27 }');
INSERT INTO table_name (id, json_value) VALUES (3, '{ "\"a\": 8": "2,3,4", "a:b":"a,b,c", "x": true, "y": false, "z": null, "n": -0e100 }');
INSERT INTO table_name (id, json_value) VALUES (4, '    {   "\r\n\t\b\"\/\\u0020\u0020"   :   -0e100   }    ');




ID
KEY
VALUE




1
"max. temp."
"40 F"


1
"I.D."
"1\/3 in"


2
"a"
8


2
"b"
27


3
"\"a\": 8"
"2,3,4"


3
"a:b"
"a,b,c"


3
"x"
true


3
"y"
false


3
"z"
null


3
"n"
-0e100


4
"\r\n\t\b\"\\/\\u0020\u0020"
-0e100



You would then need to convert the JSON strings to their unescaped form (this is left as an exercise to the reader).
fiddle
